# Modify type of number with Haskell

Tags: haskell, instance, ghc

I'm working on a small symbolic library to perform some calculation with Haskell.

To represent symbolic operation I created this data type :

```
data MathExpress =                        -- A math expression
       MathDouble Double                  -- Represent a number      
     | MathAdd MathExpress MathExpress    -- Add 2 expressions 
     | MathSoust MathExpress MathExpress  -- Subtract 2 expressions
     | ...
```

I managed to create a `Num` instance to be able to use the operator `+` and `-` on my type `MathExpress`.

```
instance Num MathExpress where
  (+) (expa) (expb)  = MathAdd expa expb
  (-) (expa) (expb)  = MathSoust expa expb
  ...
```

and when I write :

```
( MathExpress expression ) * MathDouble 2.0
```

**It's working !**

Now, I would like to be able to use `+` and `-` with numbers too (`Double` or `Int`) to write more simply :

```
( MathExpress expression ) * 2.0
```

Is it possible (by creating an instance or anything) to make Haskell **infer** `2.0` as a `MathDouble 2.0` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to finish the implementation of `Num MathExpress`:

```
instance Num MathExpress where
    fromInteger n = MathDouble (fromInteger n)
    ...
```

The `fromInteger` methods is what allows numeric literals to be polymorphic, so `1` can be interpreted as `Int`, `Integer`, `Double`, `Complex`, or in this case `MathExpress`.  If you want to have a number like `2.0` or `42.7` be interpreted as a `MathExpress` then you'll also need to implement the `Fractional` typeclass ([as noted by @ØrjanJohansen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783360/modify-type-of-number-with-haskell/29783408?noredirect=1#comment47698053_29783408)), and in particular the `fromRational` method, which can be implemented essentially identically to `fromInteger`.

Comment: For `2.0` you need the `Fractional` class and its `fromRational` method too.